# Nginx Append Location when redirecting

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

When I go the `myservername.com/mywebsite` I am able to hit `http://mybackendwebsite.com:1234/`. However on redirects the `mywebsite` suffix is not appended back so I hit `myservername.com/myredirectedpath` which is not correct. How can I do redirects back to `myservername.com/mywebsite/myredirectedpath`

```
location ^~ /mywebsite {
    rewrite ^/mywebsite(/.*)$ $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://mybackendwebsite.com:1234/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

I have been trying to mess around with `proxy_redirect http://mybackendwebsite.com/ /mywebsite;`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using
`proxy_redirect ~^/(.*) $scheme://$http_host/mywebsite/$1;`